# Console Error Syntax Error: Unexpected Identifier On Double Click Tag

Tags: javascript, adobe, double-click-advertising

We modified some tags for Adobe DTM and I am getting an unexpected identifier error during testing. Can anyone please help me spot anything I may have missed?

```
var axel = Math.random() + "";
var a = axel * 10000000000000;
var s = '//2084210.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=2084210;type=confi935;cat=natio723;qty=1;cost=[Revenue];u11=' + _satellite.getVar('Reservation Total') + ';u12=' + _satellite.getVar('CID') + ';u13=' + _satellite.getVar('Renter City') + ';u14=' + [Start Location Code] + ';u15=' + [Euro Revenue (FR&IT)] + ';u16=' + _satellite.getVar('Reservation Prepaid') + ';u17=' + [Payment Card Type] + ';u18=' + [Expiry Date] + ';u19=' + _satellite.getVar('Reservation Confirmation Number') + ';u20=' + _satellite.getVar('Station ID') + ';u6=' + [Activity Count] + ';u5=' + [Activity Revenue] + ';u4=' + _satellite.getVar('Booking Country Code') + ';u3=' + _satellite.getVar('Country Residence Code') + ';u2=' + [ACRISS Code] + ';u10=' + _satellite.getVar('Reservation Length') + ';u9=' + _satellite.getVar('Reservation Car Class') + ';u1=' + [Transaction ID] + ';u7=' + _satellite.getVar('Reservation Currency') + ';u8=' + _satellite.getVar('Product ID') + ';ord=' + '?';
_iframe(s);
```

Comment: can you post the specific error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Barett, the problem was me.  I did not replace some of the markup left in by the analyst

var axel = Math.random() + "";
var a = axel * 10000000000000;
var s = '//2084210.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=2084210;type=confi935;cat=natio723;qty=1;cost=' + _satellite.getVar('Reservation Total') + ';u11=' + _satellite.getVar('Quantity') + ';u12=' + _satellite.getVar('CID') + ';u13=' + _satellite.getVar('Renter City') + ';u14=' + _satellite.getVar('Station ID') + ';u16=' + _satellite.getVar('Reservation Prepaid') + ';u19=' + _satellite.getVar('Reservation Confirmation Number') + ';u20=' + _satellite.getVar('Location Name') + ';u4=' + _satellite.getVar('Booking Country Code') + ';u3=' + _satellite.getVar('Country Residence Code') + ';u10=' + _satellite.getVar('Reservation Length') + ';u9=' + _satellite.getVar('Model Group') +';u5=' + _satellite.getVar('Reservation Total') + ';u2=' + _satellite.getVar('Reservation Car Class') + ';u1=' + _satellite.getVar('Reservation Confirmation Number') + ';u7=' + _satellite.getVar('Reservation Currency') + ';u8=' + _satellite.getVar('Product ID') + ';ord=' + _satellite.getVar('Reservation Confirmation Number') + '?';
_iframe(s);